# ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist when I try to migrate bd in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I cloned a friend's git repo and I'm trying to migrate the db. I started postgres, but when I run rails db:migrate, I keep getting the errors:

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file.
```

and

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

I've tried all available solutions online but keep getting the same error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Try the following

Setting Up Postgres
Create a Postgres user for the Rails app we'll create in the next step. To do this, switch into the Postgres user:

```
su - postgres
```

Then create a user (or a "role", as Postgres calls it):

```
create role myapp with createdb login password 'password1';
```

and make sure you have `config/database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password: password1

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  username: myapp
  password: password1
```

Comment: Are you sure you have installed pg?

Comment: yeah it's installed and started

Comment: i've never had this issue with pg before

Comment: try with psql -U postgres

Comment: tells me role doesn't exist when i try that

Comment: sorry to disappoint all the people who upvoted this answer but it doesn't work

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, you must be doing something wrong. First make sure you have pg installed and running, second enter the pg console, third run the create command specifying role, name of the bd and password as shown above, follow these steps and that would be solved

Comment: For many developers running MacOS you just need one simple command:
createuser -s postgres

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was:

```
createuser -s postgres
```

After I ran that on the command line my rake task to create the DB worked